# Добавление javascript в page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, события

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать событие по нажатию клавиши, чтобы изменялся текст на формат даты. Не могу найти ошибку. При выполнении просто ввожу цифры - и ничего не происходит. Помогите найти ошибку.

Asp.net c# framework 2.0 javascript

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                dr.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "myFun('"+dr+"');");
                if (!IsPostBack) 
    ...
    }

   <script type="text/javascript">
         function myFun(obj) {
             if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(obj.value)) {
                 this.value += ".";
             }
         }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас туда, похоже, строка передаётся

```
myFun(obj)
```

`dr.toString()`?

Comment: Да, в этом и была ошибка, спасибо. Я просто уже сам нашел ответ и забыл здесь дописать. Во первых, не this , а obj.value += "." 
  Bо вторых , не dr a dr.ClientID .